# how i can parse array of objects as one string to objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i got this

```
[ '{ "weekDay": "5eb8188ef903945ad42c3146", "startHour": 9, "endHour": 15 },{ "weekDay": "5eb8188ef903945ad42c3146", "startHour": 9, "endHour": 15 }' ]
```

i wanna to be like this

```
[{ "weekDay": "5eb8188ef903945ad42c3146", "startHour": 9, "endHour": 15 },{ "weekDay": "5eb8188ef903945ad42c3146", "startHour": 9, "endHour": 15 }]
```

Comment: use regex to remove unwanted characters and then JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stringArray = [ '{ "weekDay": "5eb8188ef903945ad42c3146", "startHour": 9, "endHour": 15 },{ "weekDay": "5eb8188ef903945ad42c3146", "startHour": 9, "endHour": 15 }' ];

let matchedObjects = stringArray[0].match(/{.*?}/g);
let arrayOfObjects = matchedObjects.map(function(item){
    return JSON.parse(item);
});
```